# Figure for taxi ride from LAS Las Vegas airport to the MGM

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, fares, las-vegas, las

I hope this isn't too far off topic...

Could someone give me a rough figure for how much a taxi ride would cost from Las Vegas LAS airport to the [MGM](https://www.google.ie/maps/dir//MGM+Grand,+3799+South+Las+Vegas+Boulevard,+Las+Vegas,+NV+89109,+United+States/@36.102576,-115.170253,17z/data=!3m1!5s0x80c8c5cc93820bd3:0x6c1168e3473cbd5b!4m12!1m3!3m2!1s0x80c8c5cc93820e25:0x9dd94505bd76107f!2sMGM+Grand!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c8c5cc93820e25:0x9dd94505bd76107f!2m2!1d-115.170253!2d36.102576) casino?

I found this interesting [article](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2014/09/19/las-vegas-taxi-excitement/) about possible Taxi driver *scams* on the route I'm asking about. I'll add it here in case anyone wants to give it a read.

Comment: Expect to pay a lot more for the trip from the airport to the hotel than you will later from the hotel to the airport. It's called "long hauling" and there seems to be no way to prevent it so sit back and enjoy your scenic tour.

Comment: @KateGregory yeah I've read they take you the long way *from* the airport but the short way *to* the airport.

Comment: I heard that you should tell them "no tunnel" so that they don't take you the long way, which always involves going through some prominent tunnel.

Comment: @KateGregory Excellent search term you mentioned: "long-hauling". [Here's](http://www.reviewjournal.com/news/traffic-transportation/long-hauling-problem-insight-two-las-vegas-cabdrivers) an article that says it's not always robbery (but usually is). "No tunnel" ought to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$17 plus tip according to http://www.taxifarefinder.com/

But it's only a couple miles, you could walk in 30-40 minutes if you're price-sensitive!

Comment: Not so much price-sensitive, as lazy as sin. Cheers for John

Comment: From LAS it takes about 20 minutes on the [bus](http://www.rtcsnv.com/wp-content/uploads/routes/2014/09/WAX.pdf) to get to the MGM. The return trip only takes about 10 minutes. I think the bus costs $6.

Comment: I have walked from the airport to the MGM. Quite a pleasant walk :)